# Current Keyboard Layout On Windows 10

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook

I am writing a program that monitors a pressed key (at any process).
I am successfully getting the pressed key, but the only problem is that I get that key at English, even though the pressed key was of another language (lets say Spanish).
So, I thought of a solution: create a dictionary of key codes and their Spanish definitions, and identify the keyboard language at the moment of the key press.

Do you think that is a good solution?
If so - my problem is that I cannot get the current keyboard language (on my Windows 10 machine). I have tried several ways, like:

```
1. GetKeyboardLayout

2. CultureInfo

3. InputLanguage
```

Comment: I don't think you would need to do all that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br206804 I believe the libraries above should help determine the language - it might also help determine the keys without having to do a key-value mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't find a working (for Win10) solution. You are correct with the fact that I should be doing key-value mapping, because I have the Key Code, but is there a way?

Comment: Related: [my function `Get-KeyboardLayoutForPid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59038452/3439404)  and [`ToUnicodeEx`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ToUnicodeEx.html).